# cannot resolve symbol HorizontalListView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-studio

I am trying to declare a horizontal listview in my activity like this

```
  private LinearLayout lay;
  HorizontalListView listview;
```

however the   HorizontalListView is highlighted in red and I get the error "Cannot resolve symbol HorizontalListView "

**Java File**

```
package com.xera.deviceinsight.home;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class SensorCharts  extends Activity{

   private LinearLayout lay;
   HorizontalListView listview;
   private double highest;
   private int[] grossheight;
   private int[] netheight;
   private Double[] grossSal= {15000.0,15000.0,15000.25,15000.1,
         15000.0,15000.0,15000.0,15000.0,
         15000.25,15000.1,15000.0,15000.0};

   private Double[] netSal = {12000.0,13000.0,14000.25,10000.1,
         10000.0,9000.0,12000.0,13000.0,
         14000.25,10000.1,10000.0,9000.0};

   private String[] datelabel = {"Jan 12","Feb 12","Mar 12",
         "Apr 12","May 12","Jun 12",
         "Jul 12","Aug 12","Sep 12",
         "Oct 12","Nov 12","Dec 12"};


   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance)
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstance);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      lay = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlay);
      listview = (HorizontalListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

      List<Double> b = Arrays.asList(grossSal);
      highest = (Collections.max(b));

      netheight = new int[netSal.length];
      grossheight= new int[grossSal.length];
      //updateSizeInfo();

   }

   public class bsAdapter extends BaseAdapter
   {
      Activity cntx;
      String[] array;
      public bsAdapter(Activity context,String[] arr)
      {
         // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
         this.cntx=context;
         this.array = arr;

      }

      public int getCount()
      {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         return array.length;
      }

      public Object getItem(int position)
      {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         return array[position];
      }

      public long getItemId(int position)
      {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         return array.length;
      }

      public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
      {
         View row=null;
         LayoutInflater inflater=cntx.getLayoutInflater();
         row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);

         DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
         final TextView title    =   (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.title);
         TextView tvcol1 =   (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.colortext01);
         TextView tvcol2 =   (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.colortext02);

         TextView gt     =   (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text01);
         TextView nt     =   (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text02);

         tvcol1.setHeight(grossheight[position]);
         tvcol2.setHeight(netheight[position]);
         title.setText(datelabel[position]);

         gt.setText(df.format(grossSal[position]/1000)+" k");
         nt.setText(df.format(netSal[position]/1000)+" k");

         tvcol1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
               Toast.makeText(SensorCharts.this, "Month/Year: "+title.getText().toString()+"\nGross Sal: "+grossSal[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
         });

         tvcol2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
               Toast.makeText(SensorCharts.this, "Month/Year: "+title.getText().toString()+"\nNet Sal: "+netSal[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
         });

         return row;
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
      updateSizeInfo();
   }
   private void updateSizeInfo() {

      /** This is onWindowFocusChanged method is used to allow the chart to
       * update the chart according to the orientation.
       * Here h is the integer value which can be updated with the orientation
       */
      int h;
      if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 1)
      {
         h = (int) (lay.getHeight()*0.5);
         if(h == 0)
         {
            h = 200;
         }
      }
      else
      {
         h = (int) (lay.getHeight()*0.3);
         if(h == 0)
         {
            h = 130;
         }
      }
      for(int i=0;i<netSal.length;i++)
      {
         netheight[i] = (int)((h*netSal[i])/highest);
         grossheight[i] = (int)((h*grossSal[i])/highest);
         System.out.println("net width[i] "+netheight[i]+"gross width[i] "+grossheight[i]);
      }
      listview.setAdapter(new bsAdapter(this,datelabel));
   }
}
```

this is part of my xml I where I have the horizontal listview

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="#fff"
              android:id="@+id/linearlay">
   <TextView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:padding="10dp"
      android:textSize="16sp"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:textColor="#000"
      android:text="Bar Chart with out any jar"/>

   <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:padding="15dp"
      android:background="#ddd"
      android:orientation="horizontal">


        </RelativeLayout>

           <com.xera.deviceinsight.home.HorizontalListView
              android:id="@+id/listview"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:background="#ddd"
              />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you trying to use a library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to read [this](https://github.com/MeetMe/Android-HorizontalListView) article which specifies how to use an HorizontalListView.

Declare your HorizontalListView in your XML and give it an id. Then you can use your element in your java functionality.

**EDIT:**

[Here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/implementing-a-horizontal-listview-guide) you have a tutorial about how implement easily a HorizontalListView. If you want a more customized version, read [this](http://thedeveloperworldisyours.com/android/horizontal-listview-on-android/).

There is a third option, which is [here](https://github.com/MeetMe/Android-HorizontalListView/blob/master/AndroidHorizontalListView/src/com/meetme/android/horizontallistview/HorizontalListView.java), where you can implement all the methods of HorizontalListView and use them (like mRect, setX, setY, onClickListener...).

Comment: @Zidane could you please add your java file too? Thanks

Comment: @Zidane I have read the GitHub Meetme documentation and today, at Oct. 2016, Android-Studio doesn't support the old HorizontalListView version that they have, because they haven't updated it for a long time. So... I have edited my post and you can find two ways to implement yours own HorizontalListView. I tried to import the library using the URI they let us but it didn't work so the second option I give you is the unique way to use an HorizontalListView. Have a good day Zidane.

Comment: Thanks a million Carlos let me have a look at it